# Best practice for joining display properties in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

We've recently made the switch over to EF Core at our company, and for the last 20+ years we've used stored procedures for our ORM.

I know EF core generates queries that run at the database level rather than enumerating through the data within memory.

I'm not totally sure how to ask this question so let me give you some scenarios!

These code snippets are trimmed down and extracted from a large customer system.

**Scenario 1 (the old way):**

Take the object 'Membership_InsuranceExtension'. This stores the relationship between a Membership and an InsuranceExtension. Static data regarding the Insurance Extension is stored in another table, named 'tbl_MembershipLevel_InsuranceExtension'

When there is a need to fetch a large list of an object (can be thousands+ of rows returned in the same result set). We create an extra class/object called xxxx_SummaryItem. This contains properties such as StatusName and InsuranceExtensionName which need to be joined... A 'trimmed down' version of the object used purely for display purposes.

This works well, and is pretty fast but there doesn't seem to be a 'native' way of doing this in EF Core without loading the entire 'child object' (unless I am missing something!)

Example stored procedure below:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Membership_InsuranceExtension_FetchSummaryList] 
      @MembershipID             uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
    tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.MembershipInsuranceExtensionID
  , tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.Created
  , tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.LastUpdated

  , tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.MembershipID
  , tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.StatusID
  , tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension_Status.[Name] AS StatusName

  , tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.InsuranceExtensionID
  , tbl_MembershipLevel_InsuranceExtension.[Name] AS InsuranceExtensionName
  , tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.ValidFrom
  , tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.ValidTo

FROM
    tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_MembershipLevel_InsuranceExtension ON tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.InsuranceExtensionID = tbl_MembershipLevel_InsuranceExtension.InsuranceExtensionID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension_Status ON tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.StatusID = tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension_Status.InsuranceExtensionStatusID 


WHERE
    tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.MembershipID = @MembershipID

ORDER BY 
    tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.Created
```

**Scenario 2 (the EF Core way)**

I guess this is less of a scenario and more of a question, but what is the best way to recreate this behaviour within EF without loading the full object (MembershipLevel_InsuranceExtension) in this case for every row returned by the query?

**Entities (for example)**

`BaseEntity` contains the PK, Created/LastUpdated fields

Child entities are currently being eager loaded with the .Include method in my repository.

```
    public class Membership : BaseEntity
    {

        public Membership() : base()
        {
            ValidFrom = DateTime.Today.Date;
            ValidTo = ValidFrom.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);

        }

        public virtual List<Membership_InsuranceExtension> InsuranceExtensions { get; set; }

        public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }


    }


    public class Membership_InsuranceExtension : BaseEntity
    {

        public enum InsuranceExtensionStatusType
        {
            Unknown = 0,
            Unverified = 1,
            Verified = 2,
            Rejected = 3,
            Cancelled = 4,
            Deleted = 100
        }


        public Membership_InsuranceExtension(Membership membership) : base()
        {
            Status = InsuranceExtensionStatusType.Unverified;

            Membership = membership;

            ValidFrom = membership.ValidFrom;
            ValidTo = membership.ValidTo;

        }

        public Guid MembershipID { get; set; }
        public virtual Membership Membership { get; set; }


        [Column("StatusID")]
        public InsuranceExtensionStatusType Status { get; set; }

        public Guid InsuranceExtensionID { get; set; }
        public virtual MembershipLevel_InsuranceExtension InsuranceExtension { get; set; }

        public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }


    }



    public class MembershipLevel_InsuranceExtension : BaseEntity
    {



        public MembershipLevel_InsuranceExtension() : base()
        {
            Name = String.Empty;
            Description = String.Empty;

        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: FYI, I *strongly* recommend getting into the *good* habit of aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to prefix your column names. `MIE.Created`, for example, is much easier to read than `tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.Created`, and `MIE.InsuranceExtensionID = MLIE.InsuranceExtensionID` is vastly better than `tbl_Membership_InsuranceExtension.InsuranceExtensionID = tbl_MembershipLevel_InsuranceExtension.InsuranceExtensionID`

Comment: Noted, thank you!

Comment: That is used to return the name of the status enum from the look-up table. I don't have access to the actual source code at this moment, I recreated that stored procedure from memory so it's a little messy.Thinking about it now, they should also probably be `INNER JOIN`

Comment: I can answer this question, but, do you have classes for these tables? I'm interested in navigation properties.

Comment: With navigation properties it is simple, please post them, at least fields used in this query and navigation properties.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv OP Updated :)

Comment: Are you not allowed to use stored procedures in conjunction with EF?

Comment: @AndrewMorton We could, and i'm sure it has valid uses. But it feels like it falls outside of the "conventions of EF". I am just trying to sharpen my skills here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create helper class with extension methods which mimic your current functionality. Note that query can be inaccurate because no all fileds amd vagigations present:

```cs
public static partial class DatabaseFunctions
{

    public class MembershipInsuranceExtensionResult
    {
        public int MembershipInsuranceExtensionID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public int MembershipID { get; set; }
        public int StatusID { get; set; }
        public string StatusName { get; set; }
        public int InsuranceExtensionID { get; set; }
        public string InsuranceExtensionName { get; set; }
        public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
    }
    
    public static IQueryable<MembershipInsuranceExtensionResult> usp_Membership_InsuranceExtension_FetchSummaryList(this MyDbContext context, Guid membershipID)
    {
        var query = 
            from insuranceExtension in context.MembershipInsuranceExtension
            join insuranceStatus in context.MembershipInsuranceExtensionStatus on insuranceExtension.StatusID equals insuranceStatus.InsuranceExtensionStatusID into insuranceStatusJoin
            from insuranceStatus in insuranceStatusJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where insuranceExtension.MembershipID == membershipID
            orderby insuranceExtension.Created
            select new MembershipInsuranceExtensionResult
            {
                MembershipInsuranceExtensionID = insuranceExtension.MembershipInsuranceExtensionID,
                Created = insuranceExtension.Created,
                LastUpdated = insuranceExtension.LastUpdated,
                MembershipID = insuranceExtension.MembershipID,
                StatusID = insuranceExtension.StatusID,
                StatusName = insuranceStatus.Name,
                InsuranceExtensionID = insuranceExtension.InsuranceExtensionID,
                InsuranceExtensionName =  insuranceExtension.InsuranceExtension.Name,
                ValidFrom = insuranceExtension.ValidFrom,
                ValidTo = insuranceExtension.ValidTo
            };
        return query;        
    }
}
```

In your code, just call:

```cs
var result = await context.usp_Membership_InsuranceExtension_FetchSummaryList(someId)
    .ToListAsync();
```

It also gives another benefits, you can manipulate with query:

```cs
var query = context.usp_Membership_InsuranceExtension_FetchSummaryList(someId);

// add additional filter
var query = query.Where(x => x.Created > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));

// get only 10 records
var query = query.Take(10);

// finally execute query with applied filter and records limitation
var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

EF Core should generate near optimal query without retrieving full objects from database.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a play with this when I get time tomorrow. If it works for me (though it looks like it should!) I'll come back and mark as accepted answer :)

Comment: On 2nd thoughts. Can/should AutoMapper be implemented into this solution?

Comment: I do not see Automapper benefits here. For sure you can try `ProjectTo`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes. EF can manage scenarios like this quite well. You do not need to explicitly join entities together like you would with SQL.

Instead you set up entities to reflect the tables they will be data drawing from and reference other related entities through what are called navigation properties. These are associated as 1-to-1 or 1-to-many or many-to-many relationships based on the table structure through their respective FKs.

EF does support the explicit `Join` but this is actually intended only to support loose associations where you don't have a dedicated FK (such as OwnerType + OwnerID scenarios to point to a reference in one of two or more tables).

Once you have the relationships mapped, selecting just a sub-set of data is an operation called projection which can be done using `Select` or through supporting mappers. For instance Automapper supports this via `ProjectTo`. So you can define a DTO or ViewModel with the fields you want cherry picked from the entity and it's related entities, then populate that DTO /w `Select`.

This does not involve loading entities into memory, so no eager or lazy loading. EF uses the entity definitions to build an SQL SELECT statement for just the columns you want to consume. It does the heavy lifting that you would have written in a stored procedure or view to fetch a subset of data.

Unfortunately a great many EF examples out there define entities and relations but then don't really cover Projection for read operations, instead loading entire entity graphs into memory. This is honestly only needed when you want to update an entity graph. For read operations projection is the way to go.